# SIGTSTP Handler terminates both parent and child process

Tags: c, linux, makefile, fork

**My Goal:** I have a simple c program that should overwrite the default SIGTSTP handler with my own, and send a SIGTSTP only to the child process.

**My Issue:** The kill call within the SIGTSTP handler stops the parent process, and exits my program (not just the child). What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** This problem seems to only happen when I compile and run my code using the following make command: `gcc -o program *.c -lreadline && ./program`. It seems (the `make` process?) is terminated because my output contains the following line upon ctrl-z:
`gcc -o sandbox *.c -lreadline && ./sandbox`
Is there a way to both get my program to have the desired functionality and use make?

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int child;

void handler();

static void SIGTSTP_Handler()
{
  if (child != 0) {
    kill(child, SIGTSTP);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGTSTP, SIGTSTP_Handler);

  child = fork();

  if (child == 0) {   
    setpgid(0, getpid());

    printf("CHILD's PID ::: [ %d ]\n", getpid());

    printf("CHILD's GROUP ::: %d\n", getpgrp());

    execlp("sleep", "sleep", "30", NULL);

  }
  else {
    setpgid(child, child);

    int status;

    printf("CHILD's PID (From Parent Perspective) ::: [ %d ]\n", child);

    printf("PARENT's PID ::: %d\n", getpid());

    printf("PARENT's GROUP ::: %d\n", getpgrp());

    waitpid(child, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
  }

  while (1);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending SIGTSTP (ie. control + __Z__ , not control + __C__). And the handler is the same for child and parent. Works fine on my system.

Comment: I don't see a reason for the `setpgid` calls at first glance [and they may be responsible for the difficulty you're having]. You probably want to do different things in parent/child. Parent: `signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_IGN)`. Child: `signal(SIGTSTP,SIGTSTP_Handler)` Also, having `SIGTSTP_Handler` send itself a signal doesn't help since it only gets invoked if the signal has already been sent to the process externally (e.g. child gets the signal and then sends the _same_ signal to itself).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I set the Handler for the parent so that I can catch the `SIGTSTP` and redirect it to the child. I suppose I could also just add `signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN)` to the parent and do nothing for signal handling in the child. I think the problem may be that I run my code with a make command because I see the following when my program stops:  `[2]+  Stopped                 make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused because the `make` command that I started my program using was terminated by `ctrl-z`. To fix the problem you can either:

**OLD Problematic Make Command:**

`gcc -o program *.c && ./program`

**Potential Solutions:**

(1) Remove the `&& ./program` line from the make command

(2) Compile and run your program without using make

*I am unsure if there is anyway to still use start the program using make if you are hoping to keep your main program running in the case of a `SIGTSTP` signal*